# Laravel How to reference model outside of package?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 8 with a custom package. I have models in this package and outside this package, for example User (from default auth) and thread model (in a package). I've got thread-user relationship belongsToMany for "like"-system that I need to have working. here is a piece of code, of thread model.

```
namespace LaraChan\Core\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use LaraChan\Core\Traits\Renderable;
use LaraChan\Core\Traits\Uuids;
use LaraChan\Core\Traits\Image;
use App\Models\User;

class Thread extends Model
{
use Uuids, Image, Renderable;
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'board',
    'title',
    'image',
    'body',
    'user_author'
];


public function userlikes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'threads_liked', 'thread_id', 'user_id');
}
}
```

it does not seem to me that relationship is working. I've used Larachan package. https://github.com/anthonybudd/LaraChan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reference a model outside of a package in **Laravel**, you can use the full namespace of the model.

For example, if your model is located in the `App\Models` namespace, you can reference it like this:

```
$model = App\Models\MyModel::find(1);
```

Comment: Thanks! Please check if this is what you meant:
public function userlikes(){
        $model = App\Models\User::find(1);
        return $this->belongsToMany($model, 'threads_liked', 'thread_id', 'user_id');
    }
I tried it and it still trying to reference a name within this namespace: Class "LaraChan\Core\Models\App\Models\User" not found

Comment: The problem is that the namespace for the User model is incorrect. The correct namespace should be "LaraChan\Core\Models\User". @Critic